# Указатель на буфер, альтернатива на java

Tags: java, c++, c, сетевое-программирование

Вот например на си и с++ я передаю буфер, этот буфер строился из структуры. И вот например я получаю этот буфер по сети, накладываю указатель на структуру и получаю данные структуры.

```
struct i {
  int i;
  char s;
};
struct i *i = &buf[0];
printf ( "%d\n", i->i );
```

Какая есть алтернатива в java? Я немного посмотрел в книге и нашел что можно сеарилизовать объект, но нашел только в файл. В документации не нашел информации о функции наподобии этой **putObject()**, которая могла бы сеарилизовать в буфер для передачи по сети. Да и ещё где-то читал, что сериализацию хотят или убрали уже в новых версиях java. Вообще не пойму как можно обработать данные по сети в java, это же какой-то кошмар, если нет указателей. С указателями я мог бы делать так.

```
struct number {
  int n;
};
struct ver {
  int n;
  int v;
};
struct her {
  int n;
  short v;
};
struct number *n = &buf[0];
switch ( n->n ) {
  case 0:
    struct ver *v = &buf[0];
    printf ( "%d\n", v->v );
    break;
  case 1:
    struct her *h = &buf[0];
    printf ( "%d\n", h->v );
    break;
}
```

}

Comment: всегда есть jni. Там есть указатели и печеньки.

Comment: У меня скоро будет книга по jni, но я недумаю что через jni можно передать класс или структуру. Скорее всего через jni можно передать либо строку, либо число, а это не то. Нужно комплект данных передать.

Comment: @xverizex передавайте сериализованный массив байт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможные варианты решения:

1. Объявить два метода Serialize/Deserialize и вручную все сделать для каждого поля
2. Написать универсальный сериализатор/десериализатор и обработать все поля через рефлексию
3. Воспользоваться одной из библиотек для сериализации/десериализации. Например `gson`
4. Воспользоваться одной из библиотек для передачи объектов по сети. Например `apache thrift`

Comment: А можно какие нибудь примеры кода, как это делается?